# Facebook ignores og:title and og:image

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-opengraph

Facebook OG **scraper** worked fine til last few days. But now, when I try to share a link from my website to my Facebook page, it sometimes ignores og:image and always ignores the og:title value now.
When I try to **scrape** this url: http://zdaniklame.cz/obrazek/525-jsou-barvy-stejne-zakryjte-si-prstem-delici-caru, which obviously has all the required og:tags in source code, Facebook OG debugger shows this:

```
Raw Open Graph Document Information
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:title" content="" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="article:author" content="http://facebook.com/trolololcz" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:description" content="optick&#xe9; klamy, iluze, stereogramy a klamaj&#xed;c&#xed; fotky" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:url" content="http://zdaniklame.cz/obrazek/525-jsou-barvy-stejne-zakryjte-si-prstem-delici-caru" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:image" content="http://static.trololol.cz/fbimage.php?id=0" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="og:site_name" content="ZdaniKlame.cz" />
Meta Tag    <meta property="fb:admins" content="1113873968" />
```

It seems like I left those meta contents empty, but when I visit my page in a web browser and look into a source code, everything is filled up correctly.

Comment: @samsquanc: i assume he is talking about the og debugger

Comment: This is what Facebook see: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fzdaniklame.cz%2Fobrazek%2F525-jsou-barvy-stejne-zakryjte-si-prstem-delici-caru . So it is empty

Comment: That's the problem - Facebook sees it empty, but when you enter that link and watch the source code, it is certanily not empty.

Answer (score 0):

that data is empty, in other browsers you may have cache
og:image may cause trouble since url is a php script not a image even if output is image

Comment: It worked fine, that PHP script generates Facebook-like image with proper imetypes. It stopped working like 2 days ago  and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is returning empty strings for those values - you need to fix that on your side:

I tried this twice and it failed once and worked once, maybe a caching issue?

```
 $ curl -A "facebookexternalhit/1.1" -i 'http://zdaniklame.cz/obrazek/525-jsou-barvy-stejne-zakryjte-si-prstem-delici-caru'

 <meta name="description" content="optické klamy, iluze, stereogramy a klamající fotky">
 <meta name="keywords" content="optické klamy, iluze, stereogramy, návod jak číst stereogramy">
 <meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
 <meta name="author" content="Trololol.cz">
 <meta name="copyright" content="(c) 2014 Pavel Hodoval">
 <meta property="og:title" content="">
 <meta property="article:author" content="http://facebook.com/trolololcz">
 <meta property="og:type" content="article">
 <meta property="og:description" content="optické klamy, iluze, stereogramy a klamající fotky">
 <meta property="og:url" content="http://zdaniklame.cz/obrazek/525-jsou-barvy-stejne-zakryjte-si-prstem-delici-caru">
 <meta property="og:image" content="http://static.trololol.cz/fbimage.php?id=0">
 <meta property="og:site_name" content="ZdaniKlame.cz">
 <meta property="fb:admins" content="1113873968">
```

the og:title is empty and the og:image returns nothing (due to id=0?)

Comment: Well, I'm using xCache because the site is a bit lot visited. But I used xCache before too, and it didn't cause problems like this. When I try it by browser, I always get the correct source code with filled fields.

Comment: I was thinking - the whole page loads except the content part which is in PHP output buffer. But only when e.g. sharing from Facebook. When you click on some link with image from our homepage, everything works fine.